# Twitter Queries

Tags: api, twitter

I'm trying to write a URL for Twitter's Search API.

The page says you can search for love or hate:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search

```
love OR hate    containing either "love" or "hate" (or both)
```

But I'm not seeing a way to do this.

It should be fairly simple:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%40twitterapi
```

is an example of a URL that searches for twitterapi. But how would I search for two terms? What's the operand for OR in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it appears that %20OR%20 works in this context.